# DJANGO unexpected keyword required

Tags: python, django

```
models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
```

Using Django 3.0.1 and Python 3.6.8, I get unexpected keyword argument required.Why is that?How to fix it?

Comment: `required` is for forms. For models, use `blank=False`. It's set to `False` by default, so you can just omit it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#field-options), you should use `blank=False`:

> If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Comment: Despite setting blank=False, I can still create and save an object with missing fields to the database